# How to show the canonical embedding $c_0\rightarrow c_0^{**}$ is not surjective?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

I want to show $c_0$ is not reflexive by showing the canonical embedding $T:c_0\rightarrow c_0^{**}$ is not surjective.

And I know $c_0$ is a closed subspace of $\ell_\infty$ and $\ell_\infty$ is isometrically isomorphic to $c_0^{**}$. But I couldn't find $x^{**}\in c_0^{**}$ such that $T(x)\neq x^{**}$ ($x\in c_0$). Can anyone help me to show the canonical embedding $T:c_0\rightarrow c_0^{**}$ is not surjective?

Thank you!

Comment: Think about it intuitively: Can you find a sequence in $\ell_\infty$ that is not in $c_0$?

Comment: @Aweygan Yes I can but $\ell_\infty$ is isometrically isomorphic to $c_0^{**}$.

Comment: Same question as [How to show that the canonical double-dual map $c_0\to\ell^\infty$ is not surjective?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/678576)

Comment: @SFTP I think they use different methods. They didn't use $T$ is not surjective to show the conclusion.

Comment: Okay, I added an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2711952) with the direct approach. It's best to have the proofs of the same fact in one place.